# iterate through dictionary and change argument value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, datetime

hi i have dictionary like that:

```
 days_data = {
    '2023-04-14': {'1. open': '183.95', '2. high': '186.28', '3. low': '182.01', '4. close': '185.0', '5. adjusted close': '185.0', '6. volume': '96438664', '7. dividend amount': '0.0000', '8. split coefficient': '1.0'},
    '2023-04-13': {'1. open': '182.955', '2. high': '186.5', '3. low': '180.94', '4. close': '185.9', '5. adjusted close': '185.9', '6. volume': '112932985', '7. dividend amount': '0.0000', '8. split coefficient': '1.0'},
    '2023-04-12': {'1. open': '190.74', '2. high': '191.5846', '3. low': '180.31', '4. close': '180.54', '5. adjusted close': '180.54', '6. volume': '150256278', '7. dividend amount': '0.0000', '8. split coefficient': '1.0'}
    }
```

using datetime, i want to compare the keys in days_data to yesterday, and if it not exist, expand the interval by 1, as shown in my code:

```
today = dt.date.today() # equal to 2023-04-17
interval = 1
yesterday = dt.date.today() - dt.timedelta(days=interval) # equal to 2023-04-16
for key in days_data:
    if key == str(yesterday):
        print("equal")
    else:
        yesterday = dt.date.today() - dt.timedelta(days=interval + 1)
```

this code don't work because it compare the first key ('2023-04-14') to yesterday value, and if it False it get over to next key ('2023-04-13').
what i want to do is - if the first key not equal - to expand interval by 1 so yesterday value now will be "2023-04-15" and so on to "2023-04-15" until it equal to the first key.
i tried also try and expect but i didn't work.
thanks a lot

Comment: You have a typo. `if yesterday_data = days_data[str(yesterday)]:` should be `if yesterday_data == days_data[str(yesterday)]:`

Comment: You need to update `yesterday` itself in the loop, not `interval`.

Comment: @chepner i update yesterday but it's still get over to the next key in the dictionary..

Comment: Nothing in the code you are showing updates `yesterday`. Please provide a [mcve] with the expected output for the `dict` shown.

Comment: Is the data always in reverse-date order?

Comment: yes i get it from API

Answer (score 0):

Firstly str(date) might give time also so force your exact format with strftime(date,'format').
Secondly  you do not have enough data to test your code , add few more dummy dates and test it

```
days_data = {
    '2023-04-14': {'1. open': '183.95', '2. high': '186.28', '3. low': '182.01', '4. close': '185.0', '5. adjusted close': '185.0', '6. volume': '96438664', '7. dividend amount': '0.0000', '8. split coefficient': '1.0'},
    '2023-04-13': {'1. open': '182.955', '2. high': '186.5', '3. low': '180.94', '4. close': '185.9', '5. adjusted close': '185.9', '6. volume': '112932985', '7. dividend amount': '0.0000', '8. split coefficient': '1.0'},
    '2023-04-12': {'1. open': '190.74', '2. high': '191.5846', '3. low': '180.31', '4. close': '180.54', '5. adjusted close': '180.54', '6. volume': '150256278', '7. dividend amount': '0.0000', '8. split coefficient': '1.0'}
    }
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
today = datetime.today()
interval = 1
yesterday = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=interval)
for i in days_data.keys():
    if i == yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'):
        print('equal')
    else:
        print('not equal')
        interval+=1
        yesterday = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=interval)
        print(interval,yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```